# Algorithm to calculate worst case time complexity?

Tags: algorithm

NASA wants to link n stations spread over the country using communication channels. Each pair of stations has a different bandwidth available, whis is known a priori. NASA wants to select n-1 channels (the minimum possible) in such a way that all the stations are linked by the channels and the total bandwidth (defined as the sum of the individual bandwidths of the channels) is maximum. Give an efficient algorithm for this problem and determine its worst-case time complexity. Consider the weighted graph G = (V,E), where V is the set of stations and E is the set of channels between the stations. Define the weight w(e) of an edge e ∈ E as the bandwidth of the corresponding channel.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a homework solving site

Comment: well, if you'd paid euro 800 because you didnt solve the exercise correct and failed the course, then you wouldnt be so arrogant in the comments.

Comment: @GeorgePatsias Not everything in life can be solved with a bribe. Keep your €800 or pay it elsewhere: this is not a homework solving site. There are particular rules to the quality of questions, one of which requires for you (not us) to demonstrate your effort in trying to solve the problem you are asking about. You present your effort which clearly shows that you actually spent time thinking about the problem and what you came up with, then you say sorry to those you abused and then we'll see if somebody will have a desire to follow up on this.

Comment: What kind of graph connects all its _n_ vertices using _n-1_ edges? How do you find such a graph?

Answer (score 0):

Your favorite minimum spanning tree algorithm can be readily adapted to solve this maximum spanning tree problem by reversing the order on edge weights.